# using 'data()' '$result' for dataset in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataset

```
datasets <- data(package = "ggplot2")$results[,"Item"]
print(datasets)
```

can anyone explain this like how it is working how the '$result' and
later part is working

Answer (score 0):

Break it up into steps

```
data(package = "ggplot2")
```

Returns an "packageIQR" object

```
class(data(package = "ggplot2"))
```

An "packageIQR" object has the following components

```
names(data(package = "ggplot2"))
#[1] "title"   "header"  "results" "footer"
```

So

```
data(package = "ggplot2")$results
```

will extract the component "results"

This component is a matrix, so

```
data(package = "ggplot2")$results[,"Item"]
```

Will extract the column named "Item"